# Design ListPicker Blend/Xaml

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8, expression-blend, listpicker

I am using a ListPicker, but have a hard time getting the design to work. I have included the test I have done:

```
 <ControlTemplate x:Key="listpicker_style" TargetType="toolkit:ListPicker">
        <StackPanel>
            <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                <VisualStateGroup x:Name="PickerStates">
                    <VisualState x:Name="Normal"/>
                    <VisualState x:Name="Highlighted">
                        <Storyboard>
                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames
                                Storyboard.TargetName="UserControl"
                                Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground"
                                Duration="0">
                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame
                                    Value="{StaticResource PhoneTextBoxForegroundBrush}"
                                    KeyTime="0"/>
                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames
                                Storyboard.TargetName="Border"
                                Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background"
                                Duration="0">
                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame
                                    Value="{StaticResource PhoneTextBoxEditBackgroundColor}"
                                    KeyTime="0"/>
                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames
                                Storyboard.TargetName="Border"
                                Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush"
                                Duration="0">
                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame
                                    Value="{StaticResource PhoneTextBoxEditBorderBrush}"
                                    KeyTime="0"/>
                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                        </Storyboard>
                    </VisualState>
                    <VisualState x:Name="Disabled">
                        <Storyboard>
                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames
                                Storyboard.TargetName="Border"
                                Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background"
                                Duration="0">
                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame
                                    Value="{StaticResource TransparentBrush}"
                                    KeyTime="0"/>
                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames
                                Storyboard.TargetName="Border"
                                Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush"
                                Duration="0">
                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame
                                    Value="{StaticResource PhoneDisabledBrush}"
                                    KeyTime="0"/>
                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames
                                Storyboard.TargetName="UserControl"
                                Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground"
                                Duration="0">
                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame
                                    Value="{StaticResource PhoneDisabledBrush}"
                                    KeyTime="0"/>
                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                        </Storyboard>
                    </VisualState>
                </VisualStateGroup>
            </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
            <ContentControl
                Content="{TemplateBinding Header}"
                ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding HeaderTemplate}"
                Foreground="{StaticResource PhoneSubtleBrush}"
                FontSize="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeNormal}"
                HorizontalContentAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}"
                Margin="0 0 0 8"/>
            <Grid>
                <Rectangle Fill="#FFEAC726" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="52" Margin="0,0,-7,0" Stroke="Black" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="83"/>
                <Rectangle Fill="#FF685B1F" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="9" Margin="0,0,-7,0" Stroke="Black" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="83"/>
                <Rectangle Fill="#FF685B1F" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="9" Margin="0,43,-7,0" Stroke="Black" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="83"/>
                <Border x:Name="Border"
                    Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                    BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                    BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Opacity="0">
                    <UserControl x:Name="UserControl" Foreground="{TemplateBinding Foreground}" Margin="7,-3,-7,3">
                        <StackPanel>
                            <TextBlock x:Name="MultipleSelectionModeSummary" Margin="8 8 0 8" />
                            <Canvas x:Name="ItemsPresenterHost" MinHeight="46">
                                <ItemsPresenter x:Name="ItemsPresenter">
                                    <ItemsPresenter.RenderTransform>
                                        <TranslateTransform x:Name="ItemsPresenterTranslateTransform"/>
                                    </ItemsPresenter.RenderTransform>
                                </ItemsPresenter>
                            </Canvas>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </UserControl>
                </Border>
            </Grid>
        </StackPanel>
    </ControlTemplate>
```

Basicly what I want to achieve is to create a listpicker that looks like a scroll. When you click it the scroll expands and shows the entire options. Therefore I am not interested in using the full-screen look.

I have also done other tries with similar bad success where I used designed usercontrols as the scrolls top and bottom for animations. But the design of the listpicker has been impossible to do.

My question is therefore if somebody has a design of the listpicker, using usercontrols, such that I can override them or if you can direct me towards how to manipulate the listpicker correctly. I have used blend, experssion design, Illustrator and XAML, so any method for designing the listpicker using either of them would be much appreciated!

**Visual Example**

So the idea is something like this:

[image]

Such that the text is inside the scroll, when you click it, the scroll expands with a list inside you can scroll to choose elements.

**UserControl**

[Usercontrol of a scroll](https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=0B6jlL-ovciOyfkRtQmxoZ3NMaXpjN0RaZ3RvX281VHFncE5jTHRvdFBfajNVb2NaYnA3dWM&usp=sharing)

**Pictured Overview**

The selected Item:

[image: list]

Click the element and a list appears:

[image: expand]

This is how a listpicker works I want to design it as a scroll, either all from scratch or using the tool [listpicker description](http://www.geekchamp.com/articles/listpicker-for-wp7-in-depth), is what I am looking for. I have however not succeeded in making the expanding look nice.

Comment: Do you have a visual example of what your goal is you can point people to? Having trouble visualizing exactly what you mean in your description. I'm sure it's do-able though.

Comment: @ChrisW. I have added a visual example with some text to describe. Can you help me with the issue?

Comment: @ChrisW. I have added a usercontrol such that the scroll can be rendered

Comment: So you want a scrollable area inside the area of that literal Scroll that when an item within it is selected it expands to take up more area of the scroll?

Comment: @ChrisW I wantexactly the listpicker functionality with the scroll look. So the name of the selected element is in the scroll. When the scroll is clicked it expands/rolls out such that a small view of a scrollable list is viewable and scrollable. Hope it is clear

Comment: So each item would be an individual scroll? Then when an item is clicked (a scroll) the scroll expands to show more content? Sorry amigo I'm still not 100% clear on what you're trying to do haha.

Comment: @chrisw just appreciating your help and interest since I haven't been able to make it. But what you say is not what I want :D I am looking for a field which is designed as a scroll, as on the image above. The content on the scroll is the selected text string. If the user clicks the scroll/selected item, the scroll expands into a list, showing a few of the elements in the list. When an element is chosen it goes back to showing only one element. In short the listpicker tool designed as a scroll.

Comment: So the scroll just has something displaying minimal content at first, then if the user clicks that scroll content, the scroll opens up vertically to provide a listpicker within it?

Comment: Just added a link and some more info that may help the description :D but O think you know what I mean now. Based on your comment :D

Comment: @ChrisW. Were you able to help ?

Comment: Yea sorry haven't had time to jump back to this, got too many tasks on my plate at work at the moment, will try to swing back sometime today though.

Comment: @chrisw. I have made a Bounty for the question so if you have time you Will get some for your effort. :)

Comment: Oh I'm not worried about points amigo, would rather just see you get your remedy. Mondays are usually pretty busy but I'll see if I can't find some time.

Comment: Okay thank you. But then you get some for your effort. I hope you can help atleast :)

Comment: Oh we can definitely do it, no worries there. I'll plop you out something later, but you'll probably want to go add your own graphics etc. If I don't get to it during the day (Mondays are a lot of meetings usually) I'll try and make time when I get home if nobody else beats me to it. :)

Comment: Ya know what I just realized? Isn't there an expander control in the Phone toolkit? You could easily just throw a listbox in the content of one, and bind the selecteditem to the header, then just throw the whole thing in a quick grid structure that looks like a scroll so it expands/collapses with it. Easy peasy... Anyway we'll prob want to move over to email or something in a bit, the comments on this bugger are getting looooong lol.

Comment: Haha yeah. And Yes you Are right I reference that tool in the Last link. But when I try or a designer I know to make a template/style it is not working. I was therefore hopping for some help for the initial implementation of the design. Because all my tries is not working.

Comment: Sorry amigo I honestly thought someone would have picked this one off by now. Anyway, just give me the style template for the ExpanderView control you tried and I'll show you how to do it real quick. Wish I would have had time sooner because this one's cake. I just haven't installed the WP stuff yet but the xaml will be simple.

Answer (score 1):

I have made it the most simple I can. The idea is the following: the Translate and Scale properties are animated between states, others like Height, etc aren't. So Let's create the Layout like the following:

```
 <StackPanel Width="500">
        <Grid x:Name="HeaderGrid" Height="100" Background="Red" Tapped="HeaderGrid_Tapped"/>
        <Grid VerticalAlignment="Top" x:Name="ContentGrid" Height="400" Background="BlanchedAlmond" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0">
            <Grid.RenderTransform>
                <CompositeTransform/>
            </Grid.RenderTransform>
            <ScrollViewer>
                <ItemsControl>
                    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding}" Tapped="TextBlock_Tapped"/>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                    <ItemsControl.Items>
                        <x:String>One</x:String>
                        <x:String>Two</x:String>
                        <x:String>Three</x:String>
                    </ItemsControl.Items>
                </ItemsControl>
            </ScrollViewer>
        </Grid>
        <Grid x:Name="BottomGrid" Height="100" Background="Red" Tapped="HeaderGrid_Tapped" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5">
            <Grid.RenderTransform>
                <CompositeTransform/>
            </Grid.RenderTransform>
        </Grid>
    </StackPanel>
```

Now let's add some visual states to the page, control or what you need

```
<VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="VisualStateGroup">
            <VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                <VisualTransition GeneratedDuration="0:0:0.5"/>
            </VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
            <VisualState x:Name="Expanded"/>
            <VisualState x:Name="Collapsed">
                <Storyboard>
                    <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To="0" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(CompositeTransform.ScaleY)" Storyboard.TargetName="ContentGrid" d:IsOptimized="True"/>
                    <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To="-400" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(CompositeTransform.TranslateY)" Storyboard.TargetName="BottomGrid" d:IsOptimized="True"/>
                </Storyboard>
            </VisualState>
        </VisualStateGroup>
    </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
```

And finally the codebehind for the change of states

```
private void HeaderGrid_Tapped(object sender, TappedRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        CheckState();
    }
    private void TextBlock_Tapped(object sender, TappedRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var value = (sender as FrameworkElement).DataContext;

        CheckState();
    }
    private void CheckState()
    {
        if ((ContentGrid.RenderTransform as CompositeTransform).ScaleY > 0)
            VisualStateManager.GoToState(this, "Collapsed", true);
        else
            VisualStateManager.GoToState(this, "Expanded", true);
    }
```

Now you can add fade on the text when appears and disappears, and change the colors for images, etc. But the idea is solved.

Comment: Ah see, what I was thinking wouldn't even require the codebehind etc and just sit inside of a customized style template for an expanderview so you'd just have the template as a resource, and then hit it as a staticresource where you want it.

Comment: I will take a look,but you can put the code in a user control and use it wherever you need.

Comment: The Events had to be changed, since I have a Silverlight application (sorry for not specifying it). If I change the events to tap instead the code functions. But the visual states are not changed. The code is now placed in the page but the visualstatemanager does not have any effect?